# Standard notation for Differential Equation Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

Quick question: 
I was solving a differential equation, and wanted to know which of these expressions is in the standard notation for an answer to a differential equation: 

 (a) $y^{3/2} - x^{3/2}=7$

 (b) $y^{3/2} = x^{3/2}+7$

Just wondering where the independent variable goes in this situation. Thanks!